# Nginx 2 vhost configuration files conflict and domain of second configuration file shows "too many redirects"

Tags: redirect, nginx, conflict, white-labelling

I have 2 apps in my server. Both of them are Saas and have white label feature. One of them is travel and the other is blogger Saas project. Travel project works fine.
But blogger projects shows too many redirects. I made some test and saw that if I delete nginx configuration file of blogger it will redirect to my travel project domain. 
You can check http://blogger.az domain. It shows too many redirects. But if I delete its nginx configuration file it will be redirected to jintravel.com.
Here are configuration files:

**Travel project**

```
 server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;

     server_name 165.227.173.134;

     return 301 https://jintravel.com$request_uri;
 }

 server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;

     server_name tatil.az;

     return 301 http://www.tatil.az$request_uri;

 }

 server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;

    server_name jintravel.com www.jintravel.com admin.jintravel.com partners.jintravel.com secure.jintravel.com;

     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }

 server {

    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    include sharedconfs/travel.conf;

  }

  server {
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    server_name _;

    include sharedconfs/travel.conf;

    gzip on;
            gzip_disable "msie6";

            gzip_vary on;
            gzip_proxied any;
            gzip_comp_level 6;
            gzip_buffers 16 8k;
            gzip_http_version 1.1;
            gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javas$

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
     ssl_certificate /etc/sslcerts/live/travel.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/sslcerts/live/travel.com/privkey.pem; #managed by Certbot
    include /etc/sslcerts/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/sslcerts/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
 }
```

**Blog project**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.blogger.az;

    return 301 https://blogger.az$request_uri;

}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name blogger.az www.blogger.az;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

server {

   listen 80;

   server_name _;

   include sharedconfs/blog.conf;

 }

 server {
   client_max_body_size 128M;

   server_name _;

   include sharedconfs/blog.conf;

   gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javas$

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/sslcerts/live/blog.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/sslcerts/live/blog.com/privkey.pem; #managed by Certbot
    include /etc/sslcerts/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/sslcerts/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```